# :CIN keeps printing what user entered after each loop

Tags: c++, std

I am writing a basic make change function and it is working well (pretty sure there is a better way to do this) but I am new to c++ and I am having a weird bug. It keeps printing the y or n after a user presses it and I don't want that. I dont have it cout any for it to print to the console. Also I have tried clearing the cin buffer with `    cin.ignore(numeric_limits::max(),'\n'); it didnt work, Please take a look and see what I am missing.

Update: 
Question has been answered but I did this for a class assignment and I am removing the code just in case my prof does a plagiarism check, I wrote the code myself but Im pretty sure the checker scans this site.

Comment: Well we can't even begin to understand or answer your question without seeing some sort of code sample and a clear description of what you expect versus what is actually happening.  Maybe read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code

```
if(putchar(tolower(res)) == 'n' )
```

`putchar` writes a character to the console. Not sure why you added `putchar` I guess you just wanted this

```
if(tolower(res) == 'n' )
```

Comment: Ill be honest I copy/pasted that when i googled toLower function in c++ and that whole thing showed and it worked. Thank you so much